# Почему journalctl не следит за логами?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemctl

я через ssh захожу на впс и слежу за ходом процесса через journalctl с флагом --follow. Однако, часто он перестает работать, показывает статическую картинку. Причем, если перезайти в команду, то логи будут другие, они появляются но почему-то не отображаются. Команда `journalctl --follow -u service`. В чем может быть причина? На сервере стоит убунту последняя

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте без --follow а просто journalctl -u <сервис> может заработает

Answer (score 0):

Ещё флаг `-e` нужен. С флагом `-f` журнал читает лог, но не проматывает - надо клавиатурой его вручную мотать.